# Query with or without INNER JOIN

Tags: postgresql

i do not understand the differences between this 2 queries:

```
SELECT * from etudiants INNER JOIN classes ON (etudiants.id_classe = classes.id_classe);
```

and:

```
SELECT * from etudiants JOIN classes ON (etudiants.id_classe = classes.id_classe);
```

In both cases, it does not display records of etudiants class which do not have matching in classes table.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a Fiddle on http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: They are both absolutely identical. The keyword `inner` is optional. Are you trying to use an outer join?

Comment: A join without any qualifiers as to the type of join is implicitly "inner". Hence there is no different in output between the two; an inner join was performed in both cases.

Comment: you have answered to my question but what is the difference between outer and inner ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need  left join

```
SELECT * from etudiants 
LEFT  JOIN classes ON etudiants.id_classe = classes.id_classe;
```